# Regular expression problem

Tags: oracle, regular-expression

```
 SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME, EMAIL
   FROM CUSTOMERS
   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(EMAIL,'[A-Z0-9._%-]{1,10}@[a-z0-9._%-]{1,5}\.[net|com]','i');
```

I know this is not practical or make a ton of sense, but its a constraint I'm working with: email address with upto 10 characters prior to @ followed by upto 5 characters, then a '.' and finally the .net or .com extension. This works for the most part except the 1-10 constraint on the first half does not appear to do what I'd like.
It pulls in pretty much any number characters prior to the '@'.
For example it should accept **jreed** but not **jodywilliamreed** as the later is more than 10 characters. Anyone see what I've done here that would cause this problem?
edit: I'm using sql developer with oracle

Comment: Are you sure this is for SQL Server? I don't believe it has a REGEXP_LIKE function. I know Oracle has this function. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Comment: shoot sorry, my bad, SQL DEveloper, so yes its Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the [`^`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) character to your regex, which means to match the position at the beginning of the string, like this

```
^[A-Z0-9._%-]{1,10}@[a-z0-9._%-]{1,5}\.[net|com]
```

Comment: I had tried that, but was using  it comjunction with the $ at the end of the string. This wasn't working for me. However, just the carat^ at the beginning does solve the problem! Thank you Garett.